# IceFaces: inputRichText save on submit not working in IE?

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I'm having problems with an ice:inputRichText component and saveOnsubmit in IE. When the form containing the input is submitted, I only get the original text and not any of the changes the user has made.

This is the code I use for displaying the input component:

```
<ice:inputRichText height="250" toolbar="Transfer" customConfigPath="/FCKconfig.js" id="messageBody" value="#{InvitationPageBean.messageBody}" language="sv" saveOnSubmit="true" />
```

I'm using IceFaces 1.8.2.

In other browsers, for example Firefox 3.6 and Safari 5, it all works as expected.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the save, should do it in a .java
 and in the  xhtml is:

```
<ice:inputRichText 
    customConfigPath="/js/Config.js"
    toolbar="Mail"
    height="275"
    width="600px"
    value="#inputRichTextBean.value}"
    skin="silver"
    language="#inputRichTextBean.lang}"
    valueChangeListener="#{inputRichTextBean.changeSave}"
/>
```